# Is there any way to write a snipet of code with function of "SDELayer -o register" command

Tags: arcobjects, c#, enterprise-geodatabase

I try to create a geodatabase using some SQL command and then register some tables of it with SDE.

I create an empty geodatabase using sde post installation and then create tables and other database objects in a program written by VC# using command like "Create Table" and other DDL scripts.

but after creating database successfully user of this VC# program has to enter  "Command prompt" and type sdelayer command to register tables one by one.

I need to make all the process seamless for user and user must not see any change in working environment.Now my question,is there any way that I register tables of my geodatabse with SDE by VC# code programming instead of using "sdelayer"
command in command prompt?(Any object model?)

Regards

Comment: Did David's answer end up being correct? I'm trying to do the same thing with the Java API, but I'm running into issues.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the `IClassSchemaEdit.RegisterAsObjectClass` method will help (see the GeoDatabase OMD). You should be able to QI it from an `ITable`, opened in the usual fashion (e.g. `IFeatureWorkspace.OpenTable(in Name: String)` since you've already built your GDB).

Excerpt from that method's documentation (italics mine):

> The **[RegisterAsObjectClass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/RegisterAsObjectClass_Method/0025000000vn000000/)** method will register *a table* or feature class
>   (ArcSDE layer) in the database with the Geodatabase. The act of
>   registering the data as an object class will create records for the
>   object class in the Geodatabase system tables and assign the object class a
>   unique ID. Once a table or SDE layer is registered as an object class, it
>   can participate in rules, topological relationships and relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the sdelayer command from C#, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you're looking for (silent post-install):

sdesetup -o install -d SQLSERVER -s myservername -D mydatabasename -l "X:\PathToLicenseFile\authorization.ecp"